# Prove that $h$ is a group isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

Let $S^1=\{z\in\Bbb C |~|z|=1\}$ be the circle group. The operation of this group is complex multiplication. In other words $S^1$ may be represented as elements $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta),$ $\theta \in \Bbb R,$ with group operation $(e^{i\theta})(e^{i\phi})=e^{i(\theta+\phi)}.$ Define a function $h:S^1\to SO(2)$ by

$h(e^{i\theta})=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}.$

I want to prove that $h$ is a group isomorphism, i.e. a bijective homomorphism. I think that $h$ is a Euclidean transformation that rotates points and is an isometry. I haven't been able to make any progress for a few hours though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $h$ is an isomorphism, you need to prove it's a bijective homomorphism. That is, you need to show it's surjective, injective and a homomorphism. Indeed, to show it's a homomorphism, you need to show $h(ab)=h(a)h(b)$ for all $a, b\in S^1$. Write $a=e^{i\theta}, b=e^{i\varphi}$. Then:
$$
h(a)h(b)=h(e^{i\theta})h(e^{i\varphi})=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) & -\sin(\varphi) \\ \sin(\varphi) & \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}=\\
\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta\cos\varphi-\sin\theta\sin\varphi & -\cos\theta\sin\varphi-\sin\theta\cos\varphi \\\cos\varphi\sin\theta+\cos\theta\sin\varphi & -\sin\theta\sin\varphi+\cos\theta\cos\varphi\end{pmatrix}=\\
\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta+\varphi) & -\sin(\theta+\varphi) \\ \sin(\theta+\varphi) & \cos(\theta+\varphi)\end{pmatrix}=h(e^{i(\theta+\varphi)})=h(ab)
$$
This is due to the formulae for $\sin(\theta+\varphi), \cos(\theta+\varphi)$. We now need to show $h$ is bijective. I'll show it's injective. Assume $h(a)=h(b)$. Then, if we write $a, b$ as earlier, we get, by equating the matrix coefficients, that $\theta, \varphi$ are equal up to a multiple of $2\pi$, which shows $a=b$. It is known every element of $SO(2)$ can be written as such a matrix for some angle, and thus $h$ is surjective. We conclude it's an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

To show that it is a group homomorphism, we need that for every $\theta,\phi$, to have $h(e^{i\theta}e^{i\phi})=h(e^{i\theta})h(e^{i\phi})$. The LHS is just $h(e^{i(\theta+\phi)})$, so we need
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta+\phi)&-\sin(\theta+\phi)\\\sin(\theta+\phi)&\cos(\theta+\phi)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\phi)&-\sin(\phi)\\\sin(\phi)&\cos(\phi)\end{bmatrix}.$$
I'm sure you can verify this yourself using the [angle addition identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities). Now, $SO(2)$ is just the group of all rotations about the origin, so it is clear that its elements are in bijective correspondence with the angle at which it rotates around the origin. Combining these two gives us that $h$ is an isomorphism.